# Integrals Definite substitution from this?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Integrals Definite substitution from  $$\int^{\pi/4}_{0}\frac{8 \cos(2t)}{\sqrt {9-5 \sin t (2t)}}~dt ~?$$?

u = 9 - 5 sin t(2t)

du = -10(t cos (t) + sin (t)) , this correct   for  du = -10(t cos (t) + sin (t)) ?

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar question this morning ? Could you explain what is $\sin t(2t)$ ? As written, it does not make sense.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that correct for du =  -10(t cos (t) + sin (t))   ??

Comment: Please answer the question : what means $\color{red}{\sin t(2t)}$ ?

Comment: 9 - 10t sin(t)? @ClaudeLeibovici?

Comment: If it's $ 9 - 10 t \sin 2t$, then a closed form seems unlikely. The change of variable you propose is not very useful. Mainly because inverting it is not easy, and you need to know $t(u)$ to find $dt$

Comment: @YuriyS how can do it , do you have example with way ?

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, if the problem is 
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{4}} \frac{8 \cos (2 t)}{\sqrt{9-10 t \sin (t)}} \, dt$$ a closed form is more than likely impossible.

So, either you need a numerical integration or series.

Using series expansion built at $t=0$
$$9-10 t \sin (t)=9-10 t^2+\frac{5 t^4}{3}-\frac{t^6}{12}+\frac{t^8}{504}+O\left(t^{10}\right)$$
$${\sqrt{9-10 t \sin (t)}}=3-\frac{5 t^2}{3}-\frac{5 t^4}{27}-\frac{227 t^6}{1944}-\frac{17209
   t^8}{244944}+O\left(t^{10}\right)$$
$$\frac{8 \cos (2 t)}{\sqrt{9-10 t \sin (t)}}=\frac{ 8-16 t^2+\frac{16 t^4}{3}-\frac{32 t^6}{45}+\frac{16 t^8}{315}+O\left(t^{10}\right)} {3-\frac{5 t^2}{3}-\frac{5 t^4}{27}-\frac{227 t^6}{1944}-\frac{17209
   t^8}{244944}+O\left(t^{10}\right) }$$ Now, long division to get
$$\frac{8 \cos (2 t)}{\sqrt{9-10 t \sin (t)}}=\frac{8}{3}-\frac{104 t^2}{27}-\frac{16 t^4}{81}-\frac{5257 t^6}{10935}-\frac{481987
   t^8}{1377810}+O\left(t^{10}\right)$$ Integrating termwise and using the given bounds, the result would be $\approx 1.44347$ while numerical integration leads to  $\approx 1.44025$